# is there a way to get information (Schema details) of all tables in a dataset? (bigquery)

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way to get information (Schema details) of all tables in a dataset through the java api?
I know i can get the Schema of a query  ( GetQueryResultsResponse.getSchema() ), but that's not what i want. 
What i want is to get information of all availbale tables somehow in specific project/dataset. Neither TableList or TableDataList containst methods like this. The only thing i can get is TableId, ProjectId, DatasetId. Is there a query for this if not an api call?

Thank you,
Attila

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no one single api call to get the schema detail of all of the tables in a dataset. You would need to do a tables.list to get the ids of the tables in a dataset, then a tables.get on each table to get their schema.